# Amazon Web Service - EMR - Connection refused on port 42560

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr, amazon-emr

I have an intermittent issue using EMR (Release label: emr-5.8.0) on Amazon Web Services.  I run the following services:

- Hadoop
- Yarn
- Hive
- Sqoop
- Spark
- Hive on Spark

The error is the following

```
Connection refused: ip-10-128-196-59/10.128.196.59:42560
```

The full stack trace is:

> 18:28:59.495 [Driver] ERROR
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster - User class threw
>   exception: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection
>   refused: ip-10-128-196-59/10.128.196.59:42560
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection
>   refused: ip-10-128-196-59/10.128.196.59:42560     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:41)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.(RemoteDriver.java:145)
>   ~[hive-exec-2.3.0-amzn-0.jar:2.3.0-amzn-0]    at
>   org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.main(RemoteDriver.java:516)
>   ~[hive-exec-2.3.0-amzn-0.jar:2.3.0-amzn-0]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:635)
>   [spark-yarn_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0] Caused by:
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection
>   refused: ip-10-128-196-59/10.128.196.59:42560     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at
>   io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:631)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_141] 18:28:59.511
>   [main] ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster - Uncaught
>   exception:  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in
>   awaitResult:      at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:401)
>   [spark-yarn_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:254)
>   [spark-yarn_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:764)
>   [spark-yarn_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67)
>   [spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
>   [spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>   [?:1.8.0_141]     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>   [hadoop-common-2.7.3-amzn-3.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
>   [spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:762)
>   [spark-yarn_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
>   [spark-yarn_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0] Caused by:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection
>   refused: ip-10-128-196-59/10.128.196.59:42560     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:41)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.(RemoteDriver.java:145)
>   ~[hive-exec-2.3.0-amzn-0.jar:2.3.0-amzn-0]    at
>   org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.main(RemoteDriver.java:516)
>   ~[hive-exec-2.3.0-amzn-0.jar:2.3.0-amzn-0]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:635)
>   ~[spark-yarn_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0] Caused by:
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection
>   refused: ip-10-128-196-59/10.128.196.59:42560     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_141]    at
>   io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:631)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_141]

There's nothing running on port **42560** on the machine with IP *10.128.196.59*.  I'm using all the default settings from AWS, and unfortunately I can't find AWS documentation regarding port **42560**

[EDIT]
If you run the process again, the port is different?!

Comment: Hey Geoff, were you able to get any robust solution for it

Answer (score -1):

Not the most elegant solution but using a timeout worked.  If you are on AWS, this property must be set in classification "hive-site":

```
"hive.spark.client.server.connect.timeout": "360000ms"
```